# pre-process a tree using n*log(n) algorithm

Tags: algorithm, tree

This is a homework question:

Use a pre-process algorithm in `O(n*log(n))` and then describe the algorithm to answer this question in `O(1)`:"whether node `u` is an ancestor of node `v`?"

actually I can't think of any algorithm better than `O(log(n))`.

Comment: I note that this is a special case of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor and there are known algorithms for this which find the LCA in time O(1) after O(n) preprocessing. Clearly, u is an ancestor of v iff LCA(u, v) = u.

Answer (score 0):

In `O(n*log(n))` you can give each node a list of its own ancestors, back to the root. In `O(1)`, a node can then answer either of the questions "how far are you from the root?" and "which of your ancestors was a distance k from the root?".

Comment: i think the these questions can be answered in O(log(n)). can u explain the algorithm?

Comment: When I say list, I don't mean a linked list; it can be implemented as an array or table, so that searching for an entry would be O(logn) (since that's the size of the list), but looking up an entry by its index is O(1).

Comment: it true, the size of list gives distance from the root, but this doesn't lead us to answer the question

Comment: Aren't you assuming that the tree is balanced?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat there is no information about the tree except that it's a tree with root.